# Parallel async queries with GraphQL for .NET and EF Core 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-3.0, graphql-dotnet

### Summary

I am currently migrating a project to AspNetCore 3.0 and are running into a issue with the GraphQL for .NET *ParallelExecutionStrategy* when querying for multiple things in one query. The project is using a MSSQL Server as the data store and it is access through Entity Framework Core 3.0. The error I get is:

> A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext.

I can resolve the issue if I implement *IDocumentExecuter* and change the ParallelExecutionStrategy to await each individual execution, from `Task.WhenAll` to `await ExecuteNodeAsync` (https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet/blob/master/src/GraphQL/Execution/ParallelExecutionStrategy.cs#L27).

Example query that I'm trying to execute:

```
query {
  thingA {
    id
  }
  thingB {
    id
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

Using DbContextPool doesn't seem to solve the problem either:

```
services.AddDbContextPool<DBCONTEXT>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CONNECTIONSTRING")));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the built-in dependency injection container, you should consider using an `IServiceScopeFactory<T>`. It's essentially the same approach as **Ganhammar**'s "StructureMap" based answer, except it's not a "Service Locator". The (relatively simple) `IServiceScopeFactory<T>` code is [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/238506/219835) and another answer related to this question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60645481/530545).

Answer (score 0):

We are using StructureMap for dependency injection, which is creating a new DbContext per HttpRequest, but we needed a unique DbContext for each query, the solution was to create a nested container and request the dependencies through the nested container.

```
public Constructor(IContainer container) => _dbContext = container.GetNestedContainer()
    .GetInstance<DbContext>();
```

Answer (score 0):

See my implementation that solves this proboem.
The "trick" is create scope at resolver level
https://github.com/fenomeno83/graphql-dotnet-globalization-demo